# creating enum constants with all class types?

Tags: java, enums

I have to create an emum wih class types.

Enum should contain:

```
Employee.class
Boarding.class
Address.class
Salary.class
```

How can i create an enum with above constants?

Thanks!

Comment: enum constants name are strings like `FOOBAR`, why do you need an "enum with classes"?

Comment: RC, i have to pass class types to some API. So i have to keep all these class types in an Enum.

Comment: Store them in a list and pass the list to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enums are their own type, they can't be other class types.  You want an enum that holds a reference to other classes.  Maybe something like this.

```
public enum Thing {
  EMPLOYEE(Employee.class),
  BOARDING(Boarding.class),
  ADDRESS(Address.class),
  SALARY(Salary.class);

  private final Class clazz;
  Thing(Class clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public Class getClassOfThing() {
    return clazz;
  }
}
```

You might come up with better names though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Enumss {

    EMPLOYEE("Employee.class"),
    BOARDING("Boarding.class"),
    ADDRESS("Address.class"),
    SALARY("Salary.class");

    private String value;

    private Enumss(String s){
        this.value = s;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

If you want the name of the class, then if you want the reference to the class use.

```
static Class<?> forName(String className)
```

Comment: He wants to know about the classes, not strings that look like class names with ".class" appended...

Comment: Use Class.forName can obtain reference to the Class, but to be honest, solution for @PaulHicks looks better xD